# Is it possible to change the process template used by a TFS Team Project?

Tags: tfs

We have been working on a new TFS process template to better match the process we follow.  Is there a way to apply this new template to an existing project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following free tool:

http://witsynchronizer.codeplex.com/

It allows you to synchronize templates between two projects

Answer (score 2):

There is no "template upgrade" feature in TFS.
You can try to simply update your WITs.
But then you also need to update your queries and reports and shared documents and all.  Ugly.

The best way to do this, is to create a new project using the new template (best to use a new TPC), and then migrate your work items over to the new project.

Comment: this seems to be the "supported" way, but it would be great to know if MS actually support a more practical option. The trouble with a new project is as yuou know doubt know you will lose source history